# Kind of heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following equation or at least in what direction should I think?
$$\frac {\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+tu$$
It's almost exactly the heat equation, but this $tu$ makes things bad. I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: What kinds of boundary and/or initial conditions did you have in mind? What are the limits of $x$? A finite interval, or the whole real line, or what?

Comment: @JohnBarber actually, general idea would be fine. But if it's important, I've got initial and two boundary conditions for dU/dx(0) and dU/dx(1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a new function $v(x,t)$ via
$$
u(x,t) \;=\; e^{t^2/2}\,  v(x,t)\, ,
$$
and this reduces to the ordinary heat equation in $v$:
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} \;=\; \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} 
$$

Then just do whatever you would normally do to solve the heat equation.

Comment: By the way, if you had $x u$ instead of $t u$, this would be much harder.